# How to configure IIS to ask for SSL client certificate for an ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: iis, asp.net-mvc

In IIS, for ASP.NET apps it's possible to request client certificiates for folders inside app?
Is the same possible for controllers in MVC application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it's not hard. I have created a folder with the same name as the controller, and changed SSL settings there. It worked :)